# problem with TeXworks

Tags: errors, texworks

I am using TeXworks and I am facing this annoying problem. As soon as I try to  use the left quote
  '
of my keyboard, it is immediately translated into 
 \lq{} 
in the latex file. It happens only with Texworks.
Is it possible avoiding this automatic replacement?

Comment: Ciao Valter! And now the official welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: You probably have “TeX commands” in the preferences for the “Smart Quote mode”. Make it “None” and restart TeXworks.

Comment: It was not a duplicate but reading the answers I solved the problem! MANY THANKS

Comment: Ciao Enrico! Non sapevo girassi da queste parti...

Comment: Dove c'è TeX… `;-)`

Comment: preferences is not enough, there is also a "Smart Quotes" setting under "Format". that kept me hunter for a while ...